# Django get time in local timezone

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datatables

In my django app, I am storing time in my DB (postgresql). The stored time looks like this in the DB: 2015-03-23 16:02:12.163084+03. Problem is, when I retrieve the times, the time I get is always 3 hours behind. Like in my example date time above, the time retrieved shall display as 23 March 2015 01:02:12 PM. Notice the time difference. What can I do to ensure that the user is shown the time according to their timezone?

Answer (score 2):

> Time zone support is disabled by default. To enable it, set USE_TZ = True in your settings file. Installing pytz is highly recommended, but may not be mandatory depending on your particular database backend, operating system and time zone. If you encounter an exception querying dates or times, please try installing it before filing a bug. It’s as simple as:

In `settings.py`

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Then

```
sudo pip install pytz
```

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores date and time information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

For more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/

You can test the difference in template using

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

Time zone [FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones-faq) will help you

Comment: USE_TZ = True...I've already done that. Could the problem be that I'm actually JSON encoding the query results and performing other functions with it and not actually putting the query result in a template's context?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone # pip install tzlocal

local_tz = get_localzone()
timezone.activate(local_tz)
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out. Since I was generating JSON on the server side for data tables, I just decided to return the time in UTC for starters. Then, in the front end, when I initialize data tables, I localize the time using moment.js like:

```
"aoColumnDefs":[
                    {
                        "aTargets": [3, 4], //Columns containing UTC time
                        "mRender": function(data, type, full){
                            if(data){
                                var mDate = moment(data);
                                return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("L LT") : "";
                            }
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

This works perfectly :-)